# mysql image upload blob keeps coming up with hard to read error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a image upload part of my website and it keeps giving this error
"Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '’8°€OIßûü ÷ÞÝuÀBjöÁ› ' at line 1" I dont understand what it means. My php code is

```
<?php
require('php/connect.php');
$title = $_POST['title'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$answer = $_POST['radiog_dark'];
$nulll = "null for now";
$imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];





$sql = "INSERT INTO items ".
   "(title, price, shipping, description, sellerid, date, imagename, image) ".
   "VALUES('$title','$price', '$answer', '$desc', '$nulll', CURDATE(), '$imageName', '$imageData')";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $dbhandle );






    if (substr($imageType,0,5) == "image") {
        if(! $retval )
      {
                  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
      }
     echo "Entered data successfully\n";

} else {
    echo "Oh No Something Went Wrong! :(";
}

mysql_close($dbhandle);


  ?>
```

I think it is a problem with the image stuff because it worked fine before :(
Thank You To All That Could Help!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions. They have been officially deprecated and present a security risk. You should consider migrating to MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure because your user parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_POST` data directly into the query. This creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are entering invalid character like this `'’8°€OIßûü ÷ÞÝuÀBjöÁ›` first use utf-8 and second put `mysql_real_escape`, and also try to use this

`str_replace("'","''",var); //this code find the single quote and replace 2 quote to save in db`

i think that should do